# Rand function yields uneven results

Tags: php, random, wamp

In my program, the average value of $integers[0]->occurences should be 20000.Why it's  always larger than 20000, even after using srand()?

```
<?php 
        define('NUM_OF_INTS',49);    
        define('DRAWS',1000000);

            class number
            {
               public $occurences;
               public $value;

               function number()                     
               {
                   $occurences=0;
                   $value=0;
               }
            }

            $integers = array();

            //srand(time(0));
            //initialising loop
            for($i=0;$i<=NUM_OF_INTS;$i++)
            {    
                $integers[$i] = new number(); 
                $integers[$i]->value = $i;

            }
            for($i=0;$i<DRAWS;$i++)
            {                  
                $integers[rand(0,NUM_OF_INTS)]->occurences++;               
            }

            foreach($integers as $int)
                printf("%5d %5d  <br/>",$int->value,$int->occurences);
        ?>
```

Comment: How are you calculating the average?  It must be (by definition) 20000, because you're dividing 1000000 trials into 50 bins.

Comment: Always a little higher: 20018 , 20028 , 20020 ,20022 ,20021 ,20017...

Comment: Not according to this: http://ideone.com/uZdNF.

Comment: So, it seems to be the matter of PHP parser. I tried this code only with WAMP.

Comment: Ignore what I said above; I misread your question (I thought you were talking about the average *across* the bins, not the average for one particular bin across multiple runs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that you're using WAMP.

PHP's `rand()` isn't very random on Windows (it only generates 15 bits of randomness) so it's unable to distribute its random numbers evenly enough between the 50 bins.

In particular, bin 0 will receive 656 / 32768 of the random numbers, which is about 0.0200195

Comment: But that doesn't matter.  The mean number of occurrences per bin must still be 20000.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth The mean of the 50 bins is 20000, yes, but bin 0 will always average 20019.5, because the random numbers aren't random enough.

Comment: @Neil Can you explain how did you get that 656 in the numerator?  32768/50 = 655.36 , and if floats are usually "floored"  ,  it should be 655.

Comment: Out of 32768 "input" values, each one goes into each output bin evenly 655 times. That leaves 18 extra input values (32768 - 655 * 50), and those values map to the outputs 0 through 17, so those values occur a bit more often than the rest.

Comment: Hang on; the amount of "randomness" is orthogonal to the level of uniformity.  Any evidence that PHP's rand introduces a skewed distribution?

Comment: To my answer my own question; yes!  I just looked at the source code (/ext/standard/rand.c) and although there are comments claiming that they're eliminating the skew, they're really not.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I haven't looked at the source code, so I would have guessed that they would at least try to distribute the skew evenly, although that would just mean in this case that approximately every third value would occur a bit more often.

Comment: @Neil: Indeed, they use divide rather than modulo.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using PHP's mt_rand as your generator?  It is better at getting a even distribution than rand.

you can also generate two random numbers and concatenate them to get long ones.

e.g.

```
//desired length of 16
rand16digits = str_pad(mt_rand(0,99999999), 8 , "0").mt_rand(10000000,99999999);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm a beginner with PHP standard library and I found it useful. Now the average is 20000, but the dispersion is in hundreds.

Comment: How are you measuring the dispersion?  Are you taking the standard deviation or something like that?  As i mentioned, the function above will give you more of a normal distribution.  If you are looking to a bell curve with a specific mean or variance, you can use mt_rand to feed a function that will give you that effect.  Because you are dealing with large numbers, be careful you don't write a number that is too big (e.g. by summing them all up) for the datatype else bad things happen.

Comment: correction: ' more of a normal distribution' should be ' more of a uniform distribution'

Comment: Hmm.  I've just looked at the PHP source code, the range-limiting routine in `mt_rand` is identical to that in `rand`, so they're both equally susceptible to non-uniformity...

Comment: Also, that concatenation routine you suggested will leave big gaps in the distribution.

Comment: @Tucker: Because, for example, `rand16digits` can never be `100000000000000`.

Comment: @Tucker: Measured by my intuition. Now $integers[0]->occurences = 19939 , 20048 ,19671 ,19991 ,20203...

Comment: That still doesn't help.  It will never generate a number that ends in 00000000.